# NoClassDefFoundError: org/easymock/MockType

Tags: java, powermock, easymock

I am using PowerMock and EasyMock to mock system class like `Math.class`.
But getting an error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/easymock/MockType

Class code -

```
class ToBeTested {

    public int getAbsoulte(int a) {
        int res = Math.abs(a);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Test class code -

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;


@PrepareForTest({ ToBeTested.class, Math.class })
@PowerMockIgnore({ "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.*",
        "javax.activation.*", "javax.management.*" })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ToTestPowerMockito {
    @InjectMocks
    private ToBeTested toBeTested;

    @Test
    public void testAbsolute() {

        ToBeTested toBeTestedSpy = PowerMockito.spy(toBeTested);
        int a = -5;

        PowerMock.mockStatic(Math.class);

        expect(Math.abs(a)).andReturn(-3);

        PowerMock.replay(Math.class);

        int res = toBeTested.getAbsoulte(a);
        PowerMock.verify(Math.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(res, -3);

    }

}
```

Dependencies added in pom.xml-

```
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.2</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>


                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                        <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.2</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>


                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
                        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
```

Full console trace-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/easymock/MockType
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.mockstrategy.impl.DefaultMockStrategy.<init>(DefaultMockStrategy.java:8)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.mockStatic(PowerMock.java:259)
    at com.apple.ist.ets.mia.services.ToTestPowerMockito.testAbsolute(ToTestPowerMockito.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.easymock.MockType
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadClassByThisClassLoader(MockClassLoader.java:100)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:147)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:98)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Please also add what you have tried to fix the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [API documentation of `MockType`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/MockType.html), this type exists since version 3.2. So you have to update the dependency because you are using version 2.5.